# If 1x item costs 310, how much of item would 50 get me?

Tags: calculus, fair-division

I'm trying to work out what to use to work this out. If ITEM costs 310 for 1, how much would I get if I paid 50?

I'm more looking for how to work this out so that I can apply this to other things.

Comment: Do you get a portion of 'ITEM' if you pay less than it's worth? Right now, if ITEM costs $310$, then if you pay $50$ you are not paying enough for even one of them.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, you get a portion of ITEM even if you pay less. And Jose, I have certainly made an effort. I just can't seem to figure this kind of stuff out.

Comment: @ArnieCunningham Do you know what proportions are? In this case 1-out-of-310 is equal to x-out-of-50, and you need only solve for x.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out. It's pretty simple, I should have been able to work this out. It's 50 / 310.

Thanks anyway.